# Conditional rendering issue: Login/Logout buttons not working properly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, if-statement, react-router

I am working on a React application where I need to conditionally render either a Login or Logout button based on the user's current authentication state. However, I'm encountering an issue where the conditional statement is not working as expected. Even after the user is logged in, only the Login button is displayed, and I cannot logout unless I show both buttons at the same time, which is not the desired behavior.

```
<div className="auth">
                    {
                        isAuthenticated ?
                        (<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}><CiLogin /></button>)
                        :
                        (<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin }          })}><CiLogout /></button>)
                    }
                    
                </div>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { FaTruckMoving } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { AiOutlineHeart, AiOutlineUser } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { BsBagCheck } from 'react-icons/bs'
import { CiLogin, CiLogout } from 'react-icons/ci'
import './Nav.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const Nav = () => {
    const { loginWithRedirect, logout, user, isAuthenticated  } = useAuth0();
    let authButton;

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    authButton = (
      <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}><CiLogin /></button>
    );
  } else {
    authButton = (
      <button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })}><CiLogout /></button>
    );
  }
return (
    <>
        <div className="free">
            <div className='icon'>
                    <FaTruckMoving /> 
            </div>
            <p> 
                Free Shipping for Orders upto Rs.1000 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div className="main_header">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="logo">
                    <img src="./img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" style={{width:'120px'}}/>
                </div>
                <div className="search_box">
                    <input type="text" defaultValue="" placeholder="Enter the Product Name" autoComplete='off' />
                    <button>Search</button>
                </div>
                <div className="icon">
                    {
                        isAuthenticated && 
                        (
                            <div className="account">
                                <div className="user_icon">
                                    <AiOutlineUser />
                                </div>
                                <p>Hello, {user.name}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    <div className="second_icon">
                        <Link to="/" className='link'><AiOutlineHeart /></Link>
                        <Link to="/cart" className='link'><BsBagCheck /></Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="header">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/' className='link'>Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/product' className='link'>Product</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/about' className='link'>About</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/contact' className='link'>Contact</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div className="auth">
                    {authButton}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
}

export default Nav
```

I tried the above approach but still same results

Comment: Your syntax seems like a correct one, Have you tried to console.log there and, checked values ?

Comment: First I can see that you are using `isAuthenticated` the wrong way.

`if (isAuthenticated) {
  // show logout button 
} else {
 // show login button
}`

Can you change that and see if it works better ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `isAuthenticated` the good way, if `isAuthenticated` is True you need to display the logout button else if `isAuthenticated` is False you need to display the login button.

Try this:

```
{ isAuthenticated ?
  (<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin }          })}><CiLogout /></button>)
 :
  (<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}><CiLogin /></button>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ternary operator in your return statement when rendering components conditionally. This is how you conditionally render your button:

```
{isAuthenticated ? 
    (<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}><CiLogin /></button>)
   :
    (<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })}><CiLogout /></button>)
}
```

If isAuthenticated is true the following button component will be displayed:

```
<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}><CiLogin /></button>
```

If false, the following will be displayed:

```
<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })}><CiLogout /></button>
```